# Send Message via ActiveMQ Broker Plugin

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ 5.16.1. I am trying to send a message on a topic via the **send** message of [BrokerFilter](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/BrokerFilter.html) class using the following code snippet.

```java
public void addConnection(ConnectionContext context, ConnectionInfo info) throws Exception {

    try {
        ActiveMQTextMessage message = new ActiveMQTextMessage();
        message.setText("hello");
        message.setType("abc");
        ActiveMQDestination amqDestination = new ActiveMQTopic();
        amqDestination.setPhysicalName("HELLO");
        message.setDestination(amqDestination);
        ProducerBrokerExchange producerBrokerExchange = new ProducerBrokerExchange();
        producerBrokerExchange.setConnectionContext(context);
        send(producerBrokerExchange,message);

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {

        logger.error("error while sending message");
        logger.error(ex.toString());
    }
}
   
public void send(final ProducerBrokerExchange producerExchange, final Message messageSend) throws Exception {
     super.send(producerExchange,messageSend);
}
```

On calling the overridden **send** method I am getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Topic.send(Topic.java:367)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion.send(AbstractRegion.java:508)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.send(RegionBroker.java:477)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedRegionBroker.send(ManagedRegionBroker.java:293)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.send(BrokerFilter.java:154)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.CompositeDestinationBroker.send(CompositeDestinationBroker.java:96)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransactionBroker.send(TransactionBroker.java:295)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.send(BrokerFilter.java:154)
    at com.ef.apps.amq.plugin.TopicAuthorization.send(TopicAuthorization.java:85)
    at com.ef.apps.amq.plugin.TopicAuthorization.addConnection(TopicAuthorization.java:67)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConnection(BrokerFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConnection(TransportConnection.java:844)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedTransportConnection.processAddConnection(ManagedTransportConnection.java:77)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo.visit(ConnectionInfo.java:139)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:331)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:200)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:125)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:301)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:233)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My requirement is to send a message on a topic whenever a new connection is created.

Comment: Please include the exception details, otherwise you are just asking people to guess

Comment: I am using ActiveMQ 5.16.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize both the ProducerBrokerExchange and the outbound message properly in order for this to work.  You also need to be aware of the fact that sending could be blocked if the configuration has producer flow control enabled.

Here is an example method from 'AdvisoryBroker.java' that fires ActiveMQ advisory message for inspiration, take note of the details like MessageID being filled in which are required for the message to send properly.

```
public void fireAdvisory(ConnectionContext context, ActiveMQTopic topic, Command command, ConsumerId targetConsumerId, ActiveMQMessage advisoryMessage) throws Exception {
    //set properties
    advisoryMessage.setStringProperty(AdvisorySupport.MSG_PROPERTY_ORIGIN_BROKER_NAME, getBrokerName());
    String id = getBrokerId() != null ? getBrokerId().getValue() : "NOT_SET";
    advisoryMessage.setStringProperty(AdvisorySupport.MSG_PROPERTY_ORIGIN_BROKER_ID, id);

    String url = getBrokerService().getVmConnectorURI().toString();
    //try and find the URL on the transport connector and use if it exists else
    //try and find a default URL
    if (context.getConnector() instanceof TransportConnector
            && ((TransportConnector) context.getConnector()).getPublishableConnectString() != null) {
        url = ((TransportConnector) context.getConnector()).getPublishableConnectString();
    } else if (getBrokerService().getDefaultSocketURIString() != null) {
        url = getBrokerService().getDefaultSocketURIString();
    }
    advisoryMessage.setStringProperty(AdvisorySupport.MSG_PROPERTY_ORIGIN_BROKER_URL, url);

    //set the data structure
    advisoryMessage.setDataStructure(command);
    advisoryMessage.setPersistent(false);
    advisoryMessage.setType(AdvisorySupport.ADIVSORY_MESSAGE_TYPE);
    advisoryMessage.setMessageId(new MessageId(advisoryProducerId, messageIdGenerator.getNextSequenceId()));
    advisoryMessage.setTargetConsumerId(targetConsumerId);
    advisoryMessage.setDestination(topic);
    advisoryMessage.setResponseRequired(false);
    advisoryMessage.setProducerId(advisoryProducerId);
    boolean originalFlowControl = context.isProducerFlowControl();
    final ProducerBrokerExchange producerExchange = new ProducerBrokerExchange();
    producerExchange.setConnectionContext(context);
    producerExchange.setMutable(true);
    producerExchange.setProducerState(new ProducerState(new ProducerInfo()));
    try {
        context.setProducerFlowControl(false);
        next.send(producerExchange, advisoryMessage);
    } finally {
        context.setProducerFlowControl(originalFlowControl);
    }
}
```